# Video change detection

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have been looking for algorithms related to video change detection.

Basically it will see if there is any visual difference in the current frame wrt to previous frame or the first frame of the video and show use the difference.

Can you please suggest an algorithm?

My implementation: I did read video frame by frame and converted to gray scale subtracted each frame with first frame and played the video(current frame-first frame)

Comment: I assume that you don't mean *any* change but rather a significantly large change of a certain kind, e.g., subject motion, camera motion, lighting, scene change, etc.? If you simple want two know if two frames are the same or not, the best way is `isequal(frame1,frame2)` but if the frames were captured by a physical device, noise will always be present.

Comment: @horchler isequal is more of very precise and will consider all data in the frame, little intensity or brightness changes will also be considered and i am not looking at such a accuracy as the device recording the video is a camera from a LCD Display

Comment: To help you we must know what kind of change you want to detect (and which changes you *don't* want to detect). Describe what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way you can test whether there is similarity between two image : -

> 1. Divide two image into 4*4 or 8*8 blocks
> 2. Take squared error from difference of two corresponding blocks from both images
> 3. Accumulate the errors and check it against the threshold
> 4. if less than threshold then they are similar images
> 5. else different

Another way to do it : -

As we know two similar frames can have bit of translation in them : -

Use Cross-Correlation of the two images, higher it is the more related the images are.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting any result by computing the histograms and comparing them to one another (with EMD for instance) ?

A big change in the video would show up as a big change in the histogram would

I recall reading a paper where the authors would detect scenes cut by detecting a big jump in the histogram.

EDIT: This is not what I had in mind, but it looks good. [This paper](http://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://www.researchgate.net/publication/2857629_Comparison_of_Video_Shot_Boundary_Detection_Techniques/file/d912f511294c5669e8.pdf&ei=aKXWUv_pFcWzhAfgvYHoCQ&usg=AFQjCNFZHRVav9CxC1-u8GJUerfWRaT__w&sig2=Aa3J14tv761hTy3bWG53gg&bvm=bv.59378465,d.d2k) presents several techniques and their relative performance
John S. Boreczky and Lawrence A. Rowe, « Comparison of video shot boundary detection techniques », Storage and Retrieval for Image and Video Databases (SPIE), 1996.

Comment: I tried running Histogram difference in frames with threshold the difference. I am looking if i can have a better analysis

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/scene-change-detection.html) for scene change detection based on edge detection using MATLAB's Computer Vision System toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following two approaches:

1. Compute difference on the Mat data directly (code using OpenCV):

   ```
   cv::Mat diff;
   cv::absdiff(imgA, imgB, diff);
   ```
2. Compute difference on the feature vectors of two images. For example, you can first compute RGB/HSV color histogram (24d vector if use 8-bins for each channel) for each image and then compute correlation of these two histogram vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Computing Chi-Square distance of RGB histograms of adjacent frames is one of the robust methods. You can see the implementation and usage of this method in [here](https://github.com/yasinyildirim/ShotDetection).